# Word Frequency Analysis of .txt in R Not Returning Expected Output

Tags: r, nlp

```
analyze_document <- function(filename) {
  # Read text data
  text <- readLines(filename, encoding = "UTF-8") %>% paste(collapse = " ")
  
  # Preprocessing
  text <- str_to_lower(text)  # Use stringr's function
  text <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", text)  # Remove punctuation
  tokens <- word_tokenizer(text)
  
  # Remove stop words
  stopwords <- stopwords("english")
  filtered_tokens <- tokens[!tokens %in% stopwords]
  
  # Word frequency analysis
  word_counts <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(filtered_tokens))) %>%
      as.matrix() %>%
      apply(1, sum) %>%  # Apply sum to each row (document)
      sort(decreasing = TRUE)

  # Print the top 10 most frequent words and their counts within the function
  print(head(word_counts, 10))  

  # Generate report title
  report_title <- paste("## Word Frequency Analysis for", filename, sep = " ")
  
  # Generate abstract
  abstract <- paste0("This report summarizes the word frequency distribution in the document ", 
                     filename, ". It aims to identify the most frequently used words ",
                     "excluding common stop words.\n\n")
  
  # Generate table header
  table_header <- paste("| Word | Frequency |\n", "|---|---| \n")
  
  # Generate table rows
  table_rows <- sapply(rownames(word_counts), function(word) paste0("| ", word, " | ", word_counts[word], " |\n"))
  
  # Generate conclusion
  conclusion <- paste0("\nThe table displays the most frequent words after removing stop words. ",
                       "Analyzing word frequency can help identify potentially overused words ",
                       "or repetitive language patterns, aiding in revising and refining the text.\n")
  
  # Combine report sections
  report <- paste(report_title, abstract, table_header, table_rows, conclusion, sep = "")
  
  # Return word counts in addition to the report
  return(list(report = report, word_counts = word_counts))
}


# Define filename with corrected path
filename <- "C:\\Users\\bruh\\OneDrive\\Documents\\dictionary.txt"

# Call the function with the filename
report <- analyze_document(filename)
# Inside the analyze_document function, after sorting the word_counts:

# Print or save the report
cat(report$report)

# save the report to a text file
write.table(report$word_counts, "word_counts.txt", row.names = TRUE)  # Use write.table for structured data
```

I'm attempting to analyze word frequencies in a text document using R, but the results are sub-optimal.
The code runs without errors, but the generated word counts are only a single-element vector with a value of 1.
The report generated from this data is empty.

**Expected Behavior:**

I anticipate a list of word frequencies in descending order, along with a report containing a table of the most frequent words.

**Attempted Solutions:**

I've tried the following:

- Checked that my .txt file actually has words and that the path is correct
- Examined preprocessing steps
  (lowercasing, punctuation removal)

**Additional Information:**

- R version: 4.3.3
- RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm" Release (4da58325ffcff29d157d9264087d4b1ab27f7204, 2024-01-28) for windows
- Operating system: Windows 11 Home, 64-bit operating system
- Document details: 2,000+ word .txt file

**Specific Questions:**

1. What could be causing the word counts to be inaccurate?
2. Are there any issues with the function's logic or code structure?
3. Are any preprocessing steps potentially problematic?
4. How can I effectively debug and identify the root cause of this issue?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or guidance to resolve this problem and ensure accurate word frequency analysis.

Thank you!

Comment: For context, it's typical to mention which libraries you're using in the NLP adventure. To help others help,

Answer (score 0):

You got quite a long GPT function there.

Your main problem, as i see it, is witch getting the actual tf-idf values. all the rest is based off of it.

try this:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(tidytext) # unnest tokens + tf-idf approach
library(tidylo) # Julia Selige's wonderful log-odds approach

# a dummy tibble with documents and their terms.
function_description <- 
  tibble(
    document = c("abstract", "conclusion"),
    term = c(
      "This report summarizes the word frequency distribution in the document, 
      filename. It aims to identify the most frequently used words, excluding common stop words.",
      "The table displays the most frequent words after removing stop words.,
    Analyzing word frequency can help identify potentially overused words,
    or repetitive language patterns, aiding in revising and refining the text."
    )
  )

function_description %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, term) %>%  # first unnest tokens to word level
  count(document,word, sort = TRUE) %>%  # then count frequencies
  bind_tf_idf(word, document, n) %>%  # compute tf idf
  tidylo::bind_log_odds(set = document, feature = word, n = n) # compute log odds
```

NLP in R: https://www.tidytextmining.com/
Search Julia Selige on Youtube. she's great and has lots of tutorials for NLP